# How to display page title in that default Body only page layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I want to be able to show page title in that default Body Only page layout. How do I do that?

By default it doesn't show page title/heading above page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its within masterpage,

```
            <div id="pageTitle" class="s4-notdlg" style="left: 205px; top: -36px">
                <h1 name="onetidProjectPropertyTitle">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
                        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty ID="ProjectProperty1" Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                       
                </h1>                               
            </div>
```

use sharepoint designer to move it within the body placeholder tag ;)

**EDIT**

you could try this method:

Go to **Site Action** -> **Site Settings** -> under Look and Feel click on **Title, description and icon** , type the title within the title text box.

now go to your layouts and you should see the new control added to the layouts file! and can copy paste to where ever you want to use it!

lol thanks, my display pic is crazy lol.

**EDIT**

if the code is not visible than for some reason it has been taken out ;), add it back in within the page layouts:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

bingo you should see the title within the page layouts within the body!

Comment: This code is not present in my master page. The code I have in master page is wrapped under <!--MS:<SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server"-->SOME MORE CODE HERE<!--ME:</SharePoint:PageTitle>-->

Comment: are you using a custom masterpage?

Comment: Yes I am using custom masterpage. haha I like your image.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: I tried your method but it didn't work :) I went into Site Settings and saw that a title is already defined there. But I clicked OK anyway but the page layout doesn't have any new control added.

Comment: ok so the title is defined but its not visible on the page? and it is that title that you want on the page?

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: That code you pasted is already present in my page layout :)

Comment: are you sure its not being added to the page?? have you looked on f12 developer within IE? look at the html markup and see if its there! maybe you have some css hiding the content!